# Can you store a LongLong in a Variant?

Tags: vba, 32bit-64bit, variant

According to the table in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum), the Variant type does not support `VARENUM.VT_I8` - this maps onto VBA's `VbVarType.vbLongLong`. That suggests to me that a Variant can't hold a LongLong - however a LongLong is only as wide as a Double or Currency - and these can be stored in a Variant fine, so I see no reason why LongLong couldn't be, and I wonder if that article is out of date.

Anyway, I don't have a 64-bit Excel, so could someone please check for me - and if not supported then any thoughts why?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009053)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this link that braX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009053)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) posted, my 64-bit Excel was able to run the following code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowThatVariantsCanBeLongLong()
    Dim myLongLong As Variant

    myLongLong = 9.22337203685478E+18

    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = myLongLong
End Sub
```

Here's proof of the bitness of my excel app.

[image]

**EDIT:**

[Greedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6609896/greedo) commented that `myLongLong` might have been casted to a double, so I added the `^` specification to the number I assigned to `myLongLong`.

Here's the output with the code I originally posted with the type name included for `myLongLong`.

[image]

So it looks like `Variant` will default to type `double`, but that doesn't necessarily answer the question.

Here's the modified code that I used:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowThatVariantsCanBeLongLong()
    Dim myLongLong As Variant

    myLongLong = 9223372036854775807^

    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = myLongLong
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value = TypeName(myLongLong)
End Sub
```

Here was the output with the code in the screenshot as well:

[image]

It looks like `Variant` does support `LongLong`.

Comment: Did you check `TypeName(myLongLong)` because the numeric literal may have been generated as a Double not a LongLong - would you mind double checking with the LongLong [type declaration suffix](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/variables/abbreviations.htm) e.g.`1234^`